# Parsing Gigantic Log File in Python

Tags: python, parsing, text, logging

I am trying to parse a gigantic log file (around 5 GB).

I only want to parse the first 500,000 lines and I don't want to read the whole file into memory.

Basically, I want to do what the below is code is doing but with a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop and `if` conditional. I also want to be sure not read the entire file into memory.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
FILE = open('logs.txt', 'r')
count_words=defaultdict(int)
import pickle
i=0
for line in FILE.readlines():
    if i < 500000:
        m = re.search('key=([^&]*)', line)
        count_words[m.group(1)]+=1
    i+=1

csv=[]
for k, v in count_words.iteritems():
    csv.append(k+","+str(v))
print "\n".join(csv)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `readlines()` will call the entire file into memory, so you'll have to read line by line until you reach line 500,000 or hit the EOF, whichever comes first. Here's what you should do instead:

```
i = 0
while i < 500000:
    line = FILE.readline()
    if line == "": # Cuts off if end of file reached
        break
    m = re.search('key=([^&]*)', line)
    count_words[m.group(1)]+=1
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 13):

Replace

```
for line in FILE.readlines():
```

with

```
for line in FILE:
```

to avoid reading it into memory in its entirety. Then, to process only the first 500000 lines, do

```
from itertools import islice

for line in islice(FILE, 500000):
    m = re.search('key=([^&]*)', line)
    count_words[m.group(1)] += 1
```

so that you only actually load the prefix of the file you're working with. (Your current program will actually loop through the entire file, whether or not it loads it into memory entirely.)

There's no need for a `while` loop with an `if` check to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
with open('logs.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        do_stuff(line)
        if line_number > 500000:
            break
```