# Log File Parsing Python 5 2.7

Tags: python, parsing, logging

I have searched through about 35 different questions that I have come across to try and resolve my issue. I am trying to search a text file for a word (or string) and write the line of that word (or string) to another file. 
This is what I have and I have changed it several times over the course of finding a solution. Currently, it does not write to the new file, it does create the new file, and it does not print the line where the word (string) is found it just prints () for the number of lines in the infile

```
x = "mama"
with open("testing.txt") as search:
     for line in search:
         line = line.rstrip()
         print()



import os

infile= 'testing.txt'
outfile= '618.txt'

source= open(infile, 'r')
target = open(outfile, 'w')
flag = 'mama'

for line in source.readlines():  #read all of the source lines into a list and iterate over
    if ('mama' in line):
        target.write(line)
        print line
```

The text file that it is searching are the lyrics from bohemian rhapsody. I am trying to get this to work so that I can use it on log files to find strings like "flag" and print those to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't open 2 files at once.

```
text = []
flag = 'mama'
with open(infile, "r") as readFile:
    for line in readFile.readlines()
        if flag in line:
            text.append(line)

with open(outflow, "w") as writeFile:
    for line in text:
        writeFile.write(line)
```

Here I open the first file and for each line in the file if 'mama' is in the line I append the line to my list text.
Then I open the second file and I write each line of my list text in the file.

Comment: This is not an answer. An answer should definitively be known to solve the question. Recommending things to try or asking for further clarification needs to be done in comments.

Comment: @stevieb ok I'm sorry I'm pretty new to stack overflow

Comment: No worries. You should read through all of the items in [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Is it any better?

Comment: What you want to do is not just write the file, but also ensure the matching the OP is wanting is caught and written as well. We have no idea at all whether the write is being triggered.

Comment: If this is the full solution it does not work. I'm currently looking at some of these solutions to try and find another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619695/parsing-gigantic-log-file-in-python?rq=1

I just changed it to this:
text = []
flag = 'mama'
with open('testing.txt', "r") as readFile:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(readFile, start=1):
        if flag in line:
            text.append(line)

with open('624.txt', 'w') as writeFile:
    writeFile.write(line)  

And it only wrote one line that does not have the flag in it.

Comment: Did it write the first one or a random one

Comment: It wrote the 6th line but only before the "  ,  "

Comment: Are there capital letters in your file. If so add line = line.lower()

Comment: Directly after for line_number, line in enumerate(readFile, start=1):
correct?

Comment: Still only writes that one line.

Comment: I got it! your lower comment made me go look at my original file and I thought that all of the "flags" I was searching for were lowercase but they were not they were upper so once I changed it to "Mama" it works!  I feel like a twat for not realizing this earlier *flips tables* Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Aha! Glad I could help :)